# ERROR:string literal too long

Tags: oracle

I have one column which is `varchar2(4000 char)`. Max length of data is 3189. I have checked lenghtb also which is giving the same length 3189.

we are displaying this data in one of FE tool(Speedbase) as is . However, while traversing through pages , throwing

> ORA-01704: string literal too long

Can you please help?

Comment: Do you have test code that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Please mention your database's character set.
Also show a sample of what is being inserted in the database.